# How to resolve Error: L6769E in armcc link error for an constant array?

Tags: c, armcc

I have few arrays defined in a c file and declared as extern in its header. the header is being included in several other files.
It complies in MSVC however the armcc is throwing error.
How do i resolve this issue?

```
/* example.c file */
const tUint32 BanD_arr[4]={....,....,....,};

void BandBits(){ 
...y = BanD_arr[x];...
}

/* example.h file */
extern const tUint32 BanD_arr[4];
```

```
Error form ARMCC 4.5.2 
Error: L6769E: Relocation #REL:0 in example.o(i.BandBits) with respect to BanD_arr. No GOTSLOTexists for symbol.
```

Comment: Is `example.h` `includ`ing whatever is `typedef`ing `tUint32`?

Comment: It looks like straight forward code, and is a pretty esoteric error.   (its nothing I've seen before, and searching for related information is pretty scarce and suggest this is a pretty obscure linker issue).  You may want to try contacting keil/arm for help.

Comment: for what it's worth, this seems to be related to dynamic linking "global offset table".   Do you mean to be using the dynamic linker?

Comment: In general, you should not use hand-crafted fixed bitwidth types, but `stdint.h` types (here: `uint32_t`). If your compiler does not provide this, get a new/other compiler, because that means it is not well-maintained and likey broken otherwise, too.

Comment: @FiddlingBits yes example.h includes it

Comment: The compilation commands are lacking. It is not possible to reason about the error with the given info.